# Are there mistakes in reading file?

Tags: c#, stream

I've recently made a test. There were four tasks. One of them was to improve following code:

```
public class FooFileProcessor
{
    public void ProcessFile(string filename)
    {
       Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
       Console.WriteLine(ReadAllContent(fileStream));
       fileStream.Close();
    }

    public string ReadAllContent(Stream stream)
    {
       StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
       return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

What I've suggested:

```
try
{ 
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
    {
       String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
       Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)        
{
   Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

please, review my code and show all mistakes you've seen.

Comment: Shortening the code is not always an improvement.

Comment: @denis is it okay in my case?

Comment: I would say @Corey's approach is probably the best in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that springs to mind is that it would probably be better to not create the `Stream` and `StreamReader` instances when it can be avoided simply by using the [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to accomplish the same goal:

```
public void ProcessFile(string filename)
{
   Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(filename));
}
```

In other situations you might need to avoid this, especially for very large files.  For small files and simple operations the `File.Read...` methods should suffice.

Main advantage is that you relegate the object management issues to the framework, reducing the complexity of your code.  This should result in fewer bugs and greater readability.

For larger files, especially where you are wanting to process individual lines (a common use case) it is often useful to use the [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to process the content.  This should read the lines as needed with some buffering, reducing memory consumption while maintaining code simplicity.

---

On the question of exception handling... I prefer to only put exception handling in when it is required by the specific situation, and I didn't see a specific need here.  If the idea of an exception breaking out of this code concerns you then by all means add some in.  Personally I'd prefer to have the exception bubble out than have to write all the extra code in here to not only handle the exception but also change what we do with a null return, etc.

In general I don't like the idea of always trying to catch exceptions as soon as possible.  I prefer to catch as soon as I *need* to and no sooner.

Comment: Exactly what I would have expected too. I'd say that the exception handling the OP added was a worthwhile addition too.

Comment: @RobH so my code okay?)

Comment: In regard to the exception handling - I'd say this is the latest you can reasonably catch the exception as the method is attempting to output to the user. If it can't, the user should know _something_ happened. I agree wholeheartedly with your comments though.

Comment: Remember to wrap this in a try-catch block. `File.ReadAllText` has 9 exceptions that it can throw, of which at least 3 are [exogenous](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) exceptions which *must* be caught at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your changes are too invasive to only consider them as *improving* the code. I have to admit I'm not sure what is expected here, though. You also didn't say what method your code belongs to. Anyway, here is my approach:

```
public void ProcessFile(string filename)
{
    Stream fileStream = null;

    try
    {
        fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
        Console.WriteLine(ReadAllContent(fileStream));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
        {
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}

public string ReadAllContent(Stream stream)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Alternatively to `try/finally`, you can use a `using` construct similar to the one in `ReadAllContent` method. I decided to go with `try/finally` to include the call to `Close`, which is present in the original code snippet. `Stream.Close` calls `Dispose` in its implementation, so there is no real difference in behaviour.

```
public virtual void Close()
{
  this.Dispose(true);
  GC.SuppressFinalize((object) this);
}
```

The `if (fileStream != null)` check is necessary in case an exception is thrown when trying to open the `filename` file for reading.